# New Jenkins job disabled by default

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a feature branch on Bitbucket and pushed JenkinsFile amongst other files to the head. As defined by the administrators, I automatically get a Jenkins job for that branch. I do see a new job with feature branch name but there is a strikethrough line through the name of the job on the Jenkins dashboard. I am wondering what conditions cause it. I am sure it is disabled as the round icon on the left of the job is gray.

Comment: Any Jenkins job that is created by cooying an existing job is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened. Being a Java programmer too used to Camel case I named the file JenkinsFile. So as configured on commit to the branch head, it created a a job, but when Jenkins went loooking for aJenkinsfile, it couldn;t find one. So it disabled the job and eventually removed it.

I reverted the commit and renamed it as Jenkinsfile and it worked. :-)